# Why is g++ making code that calls the next instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, disassembly

I compiled the following code using g++ on windows to test where exactly constructors and destructors calls are placed:

```
class foo{
    volatile int x;
    public:
    foo(){
        x = 9;
        return;
    }
    ~foo(){
        x = 10;
        return;
    }
};
int main(){
    volatile int x = 7;
    if(x == 7){
        volatile foo jjj;
        volatile int y = 8;
        if(y == 8){
            goto out;
        }
        y = 10;
    }
    out:
    x = 10;
}
```

I then disassembled the object and I didn't find calls to constructor or destructor. also, I found weird instructions calling the next line.

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   48 83 ec 30             sub    rsp,0x30
   8:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   d <main+0xd>            ; calling next line
   d:   c7 45 fc 07 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x7
  14:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  17:   83 f8 07                cmp    eax,0x7
  1a:   0f 94 c0                sete   al
  1d:   84 c0                   test   al,al
  1f:   74 38                   je     59 <main+0x59>
  21:   48 8d 45 f8             lea    rax,[rbp-0x8]
  25:   48 89 c1                mov    rcx,rax
  28:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   2d <main+0x2d>         ; calling next line
  2d:   c7 45 f4 08 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x8
  34:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  37:   83 f8 08                cmp    eax,0x8
  3a:   0f 94 c0                sete   al
  3d:   84 c0                   test   al,al
  3f:   75 09                   jne    4a <main+0x4a>
  41:   c7 45 f4 0a 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0xa
  48:   eb 01                   jmp    4b <main+0x4b>
  4a:   90                      nop
  4b:   48 8d 45 f8             lea    rax,[rbp-0x8]
  4f:   48 89 c1                mov    rcx,rax
  52:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   57 <main+0x57>         ; calling next line
  57:   eb 01                   jmp    5a <main+0x5a>
  59:   90                      nop
  5a:   c7 45 fc 0a 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xa
  61:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  66:   48 83 c4 30             add    rsp,0x30
  6a:   5d                      pop    rbp
  6b:   c3                      ret    
  6c:   90                      nop
  6d:   90                      nop
  6e:   90                      nop
  6f:   90                      nop
```

What is the purpose of these calls? Also, where are the constructor and destructor calls?

Comment: You're disassembling an unlinked `.o`, and you left out `-r` from objdump so it's not even showing which symbol address the linker will fill in.

Comment: It isn't calling the next line, you dumped an object file that has not been linked yet. Use `objdump -dr` to see the relocation entries for those calls.

Comment: C++ allows a compiler to perform any optimization that has no observable effects. The above program produces no observable effects, and the compiler can actually compile it to nothing. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: assigning to a `volatile` (and reading from it) counts as an observable effect.  So that's not quite true here, and isn't what's happening in this debug build.